# Problem with adding an item to an array of mongoose reference objects

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In my NodeJS and MongoDB app, I have 2 mongoose schemas:

companySchema:

```
const companySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  products: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Product',
      required: false
  }]
});

companySchema.statics.addProduct = function (productId) {
  let updatedProducts = [...this.products];
  updatedProducts.push(productId);
  this.products = updatedProducts;
  return this.save();
}

module.exports = mongoose.model(‘Company’, companySchema);
```

productSchema:

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  quantity: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Every time I add a new product to `productSchema`, I would like to add the `_id` of the newly created product to `products` array in `companySchema` in order to easily access products later on. 
To accomplish this, I wrote:

```
const Company = require('../models/company');
const Product = require('../models/product ');

exports.postAddProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const name = req.body.name;
  const quantity = req.body.quantity;

  const product = new Product({
    name: name,
    quantity: quantity
  });
  product.save()
    .then(product => {
      return Company.addProduct(product._id);
    })
    .then(result => {
      res.redirect('/');
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

I am getting an error:  `TypeError: this.products is not iterable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a **static** method, which is a method on the model rather than the document instance.

Therefore, `this` refers to the model itself, not the individual document.

Unlike the document, the model doesn’t have an array (iterable) called **products** so it can’t be spread into a new array.

Try using **methods** instead of **statics**:

```
companySchema.methods.addProduct = function (productId) {
  ...
}
```

I hope this helps.